# Find the Laurent expansion of $\frac{z}{z^{2}-1}$ valid for $0<z-1<2$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have already used partial fractions and let $w=z-1$ to get to

$$\frac{1}{h}-\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{h^{n}}{2^{n+2}}}.$$

I know I can't have the $\frac{1}{h}$ in front of the sum. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: $\;h...? ....w...?\;$ And did you mean $\;|z-1|<2\;$ ? There is no linear order in the complex numbers.

Comment: sorry yes I meant h= z-1 and i did mean to put the modulus in!

Answer (score 1):

One way, perhaps clearer, to see it -  Observe that $\;0<z-1<2\implies0<\frac{z-1}2<1\;$ , so using the geometric series development:

$$\frac z{(z-1)(z+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}+\frac1{z+1}\right)=\frac1{2(z-1)}+\frac12\frac1{z-1+2}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1{2(z-1)}+\frac14\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}2}=\frac1{2(z-1)}+\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(z-1)^n}{2^n}$$

which, of course, is the same Mark has in his answer.

Comment: Thank you. I need it in the form the sum of a_k (z-1)^k like mark has put. So i don't think I can have the 1/2(z-1) outside of the sum?

Comment: @mathematician12345 Of course you can, why not?

Answer (score 0):

A Laurent series *can* start with a negative power (conventionally, a Taylor series should have only non-negative powers).

I would expand in $z-1$ because that seems to be what the question asks for when it says $0<z-1<2$ rather than $1<z<3$.

So the series becomes 
$$
\sum_{k=-1}^\infty a_k (z-1)^k
$$
with
$$
a_k =\left\{ \matrix{\frac12 & k= -1\\ \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+2}}& k\geq 0}\right. 
$$
Note that you must have made some mistake in your partial fraction decomposition (probably forgot that $z+1$ at the expansion point is $2$, not $1$), because the leading term is half what you were saying.